# Move first table cell in a row to be in column N

Tags: html, css

I'd like to create a `<table>` like this:

```
||Mo  ||Tu  ||We  ||Th  ||Fr  ||Sa  ||Su  ||
                  | 1   | 2   | 3   | 4   |
| 5   | 6   | 7   | 8   | 9   | 10  | 11  |
| 12  | 13  | 14  | 15  | 16  | 17  | 18  |
| 19  | 20  | 21  | 22  | 23  | 24  | 25  |
| 26  | 27  | 28  | 29  | 30  | 31  |
```

As you can see, it's the days of a month. What bugs me is that I have to stick an empty buffer cell, `<td colspan="N-1">`, before the first day there. Otherwise, the table ends up looking like this:

```
||Mo  ||Tu  ||We  ||Th  ||Fr  ||Sa  ||Su  ||
| 1   | 2   | 3   | 4   |
| 5   | 6   | 7   | 8   | 9   | 10  | 11  |
| 12  | 13  | 14  | 15  | 16  | 17  | 18  |
| 19  | 20  | 21  | 22  | 23  | 24  | 25  |
| 26  | 27  | 28  | 29  | 30  | 31  |
```

Which is obviously wrong. So, is there any way I can make the first table cell of that row start in column N, rather than 1, without needing a buffer cell?

***Note:*** I know it's not a huge deal to add that buffer cell, but I'm curious if it's possible to do without. Also the styling would be a bit easier without it as well...

---

The reason I'm curious, just to give a bit of context, is that I don't want to show those empty buffer cells. I want them to really be *gone*. Here's an image of what I'm going for:

[image: table]

Here I have that empty buffer cell, and I've had to set the borders to none and the background to the same as the container behind the table to make it look like that.

Answer (score 0):

Surely the simplest layout is a 7x5 table regardless? - Just style your borders according to whether you have content or not?

Comment: Added explanation of why I want to avoid the empty cells. Might be simpler in some sense, but not really in my case. Also find them to be a bit "wrong", as there are no "empty days" in a month :p

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. You'll need an empty cell.

Answer (score 0):

With just html table it's impossible.
BTW, I'd use few empty cells rather than one spanned - it doesn't affect the result in your case but is simpler to generate and handle

Comment: I generate the table from an increasing DateTime. Whenever I reach a new month I simply start a new table, a new row and then the buffer cell with colspan set to `$date->format('w')`. I could of course use `str_repeat` and put in one empty cell for each, but meh :p